# Array code Numbers

Tags: c#

This is my midterm example questions. However, I don't know how to write code in bash yet properly.. Please can you help by explaining to me? This is very important to me.

Thank you

Comment: Can you edit the body of the question? It isn't very clear, also there's a reference to `frekans.sh` which doesn't have any explanation.

Comment: it means, there is a lot of command in bash right? such as, for example c is the letter and with cat, case, cs, chmod, chown, cp, cut... etc. there are 22 command in bash with c letter. i need them all, in order to alphabetical sequence. a, b, c, d, ... , z.

Comment: ohh.. also i rewrite the .sh name. it will be frequence.sh

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question... this should work:

```
$ ls /usr/bin | cut -b1 | uniq -c
```

please note this will count everything under /usr/bin (files, links,...)

Comment: I bet this is a working solution, but the assignment requires the use of loops and array structures.

Comment: @sal `uniq` uses loops and arrays (internally) :-) Jokes apart... Constraints are not very clear in OP's question. For example: can we use awk? That would be easy. If we are limited to bash loops and arrays.... which bash version? With bash 4 we can use associative arrays (another easy to implement solution). Etc...

Comment: Agreed. I tested my solution with yours, btw :-)

Comment: `( cd /usr/bin; printf "%1.1s\n" * ) | uniq -c` would avoid the [pesky `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) as well as the `cut`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that might fit your requirement. It basically stores all the commands in an array called "commands". This array is already sorted by virtue of `ls`. Then we loop through all the elements in that array, and we extract the first letter of each word with the `${cmd:0:1}` and store it in a variable that keeps track of the current "letter" we are working on. As the loop continues, as long as the letter is the same, we keep increasing the counter, otherwise, we print out both letter and counter, store the new current letter and reset the counter to 1 (because it's the new letter already). In the end, we need to print still the last record, thus the print outside the loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
commands=(`ls /usr/bin`)
count=0
letter=""
for cmd in ${commands[@]}; do
  curletter=${cmd:0:1}
  if [ "${letter}" != "${curletter}" ]; then
     echo "${letter}: ${count}"
     letter=${curletter}
     count=1
  else
     count=`expr $count + 1`
  fi
done
echo "${curletter}: ${count}"
```

Comment: Works fine for me, but it should also check if the letter is alphabetic... like 

if [[ "$curletter" =~ "[a-zA-Z]" ]]; then

Comment: Glad to help @Luna. To learn more, take also into account all the good suggestions from the various commenters here.